# PreAuthenticate with OAuth

Tags: asp.net, oauth

Do I need to use the PreAuthenticate set to true when trying to make an OAuth request for resource via HttpWebRequest using ASP.NET? or is this pre auth only for windows base credentials when trying to send requests to another .NET Host/endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only built-in [authentication types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zhdx9d.aspx) System.Net supports are basic, digest, negotiate, NTLM, and Kerberos.  However, OAuth 1 [can use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-27) the Authorization header.  If you implement (or use a library that implements), [`IAuthenticationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iauthenticationmodule.aspx), you could conceivably use `PreAuthenticate` with OAuth.

Comment: thanks.  This is the API for Desk.com I'm talking about non .NET agnostic.  So I hardly doubt in fact know they're not using .NET so that isn't possible.  I was just trying to make sure that I didn't need to use this in .NET to communicate with their API but I think all I need is just a header added for Auth for the HttpWebRequest is all.  I've been getting 401s and checked my damn signature a thousand times so I have to think it's how I'm sending the request somehow in .NET.